# How to set lower case for identifiers in Toad?

Tags: toad

I'm using Toad to write queries agains an Oracle database. When I write `table_name.` I get an auto-suggestion menu with all the column names. But if I choose a column name, both the table name and column name is written by *uppercases*. Is there any way to change this to be written in *lowercases* instead?

In `View > Formatting Option > Case` "Identifiers" are set to `Lowercase`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following on [Quest.com](https://support.quest.com/Search/SolutionDetail.aspx?id=SOL87658&category=Solutions&SKB=1&product=Toad%20for%20Oracle).  It works, but may have undesirable side effects.

> 1. Go to View | Toad Options in the main menu.
> 2. On the left-hand side of the options window go to Editor | Behavior.
> 3. Under the Language section, click on the Syntax highlighting button.
> 4. In the new window, under styles on the left hand side, select "Indentifer" and select Lowercase for Capitalization effect on the
>      right hand side.
> 5. Under styles on the left hand side, select "Toad_user_table" and select Lowercase for Capitalization effect on the right hand side..
> 6. Click on Apply and OK.

Comment: I'm surprised this was accepted.  It appears to change the capitalization in the code as well as in the list.

Answer (score -1):

Click on the following menu items:

```
View -> toad options -> Editor -> Behaviour
```

Then check `Use lowercase object names from select windows`